# How to add a char inside of String programmatically Java

Tags: java

I have a String with a Address - "New York NY 10024 EUA", and what I want is this : "New+York+NY+10024+EUA" to remove white spaces and add a char "+" between.
to remove white spaces I already know :

```
st.replaceAll("\\s+","");
```

Comment: You currently replace whitespace with nothing. Simply replace them with a ``+``...

Comment: So what if you used `"+"` instead of `""` ?

Comment: there should be something like stackfail.com for questions like this, but really the method name should say it all :)

Answer (score 0):

Just changing your `st.replaceAll("\\s+","");` to `st.replaceAll("\\s+","+");` should do the trick ...  Look at the `replaceAll` [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) of String.

> public String replaceAll(String regex,
>                   String replacement)
>
> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given
>   replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
String str = "New York NY 10024 EUA";
    String Str1 = str.replaceAll(StringUtils.SPACE, "+");
//New+York+NY+10024+EUA
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use **StringTokenizer** to get every single token and concat after this

```
StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer("New York NY 10024 EUA");
        String newPhrase="";
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()){
            newPhrase+=st.nextToken()+"+";
        }
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(newPhrase);
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1);
        newPhrase=sb.toString();
```